# What is the difference between “fühlen” and “sich fühlen”?

Tags: difference, verb-usage, reflexive

What is the difference between *fühlen* and *sich fühlen*? 
I thought both mean *to feel*:

> Ich fühle traurig.
>   Ich fühle mich traurig.

And why don’t we use *sich fühlen* in these two sentences?

> Viele Menschen fühlen so wie Sie.
>   Ich möchte diesen Schmerz nicht fühlen.

When explaining the differences please add examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sich fühlen refers to what you feel *inside*. Ich fühle mich glücklich. I feel happy (inside).

Fühlen means what you feel *outside,* translated by others as "to sense." Ich fühle den Wind. I feel the wind.

Comment: "Ich fühle die Winde" würde ich als Ausdruck von Blähungen verstehen. :) Im originären Sinne ist Fühlen immer eine Aktivität von Nerven und daher immer innerlich. Im Alltagssprachgebrauch werden aber auch Einbildungen als Gefühle bezeichnet ("gefühlte Verspätung von 3 Stunden"). Sollte man beim Wind nicht "spüren" sagen? "Ich spüre den Wind." Ich fühle mich unsicher. Außerdem: "Ich fühle mich geschmeichelt" - auch ein äußerer Reiz.

Answer (score 9):

Fühlen can either take

1. transitive form with an accusative object - "Ich fühle die Sonne auf meiner Haut"
2. be reflexive with an adverb - This is *how* you feel - "Ich fühle mich heute schlecht"

Only in colloquial German you can use the reflexive form *without* an adverb or an adverbial construct.

> Er fühlte sich heute nicht und ist heim gegangen

That one is a shortened form of "Er fühlte sich heute nicht **gut**" - In some regions you're apparently allowed to leave off the "gut". This one I have heard in  the Cologne and Ruhrgebiet area, but never in the South.

> Ich fühle da wie du

(The second one aligns with your last example - I consider that colloquial.  It literally translates to "I feel like you" which doesn't make a lot of sense to me because it makes me want to ask "what?")

Comment: I don't think that "Er fühlte sich heute nicht und ist heim gegangen" can stand alone. I'm really missing the "gut" in that sentence!

Comment: @c.p Hinzugefügt, wo ich es denn gehört habe

Comment: I do not think that the second sentence is colloquial. Das elliptische "ich fühl' mich heute nicht" kenne ich auch.

Comment: Sorry but i didn't quiet understand the second part from (only in colloquial German )

Comment: @N88 Can you elaborate a bit on *what* you don't understand, please?

Comment: I undertand now that fühlen means sensing something external ..wind , sunrays or something material ..stoff.    But frühlen sich feel something from inside me ex, ich frühle mich Kalt ,ich früle mich froh ,what i didnt (i hooe this is right till now ) i dont understand your last 2 examples if you can explain them in simpler language ir examples :)

Comment: @N88 Added some explanation

Comment: I don't know, what strange habits people in Cologne may recently have acquired, but the following is most certainly wrong: "Er fühlte sich heute nicht und ist heim gegangen". If it is indeed voiced by native speakers, then it is the most awful slang.

Answer (score 5):

*fühlen* really means to sense. If you want to express a feeling, you'll have to use *sich fühlen*. Consequently you can't say "ich fühle traurig", only "ich fühle mich traurig" is correct.

Comment: Thank you But can you give example on using fühlen ?

Comment: *Ich fühle den Wind in meinem Gesicht.*

Comment: _Fühlst du, wie weich dieser Stoff ist? Ja, ich fühle es._

Comment: And these two sentences why we didn't use sich fühlen ( Viele Menschen fühlen so wie Sie).    (. ich möchte diesen Schmerz nicht fühlen).

Comment: @N88: Ernsthaft? "Viele Menschen fühlen sich so wie Sie." oder "Viele Menschen fühlen mit Ihnen." Fühlen so wie Sie - ja, mit dem ZNS.

Comment: @userunknown: Ich denke, da ist ein Bedeutungsunterschied: "Mir ist schlecht" - "Viele Menschen fühlen sich so wie sie", aber: "Das ist ungerecht." - "Viele Menschen fühlen so wie sie." Und "fühlen mit Ihnen" ist ohnehin was anderes.