# What is the difference between "empfinden" and "fühlen", as well as "die Empfindung" and "das Gefühl"?

Tags: difference

Both are translated as "feel", or in their noun forms as "feeling". Is there any difference in meaning or usage or anything else?

Comment: In a nutshell: "fühlen" == "to feel" - "empfinden" == "to sense"

Comment: @tofro, und "spüren"?

Comment: @denis "to sense" as well

Comment: It's so fascinating how many of you tried to explain it yet there is no proper answer to the question . One of you saying it means psychological feelings other one is saying fühlen is used for psychological feelings xd

Answer (score 6):

"fühlen" can mean sensing something physically:

> Ich fühle wie etwas Warmes mich berührt.
>
> I feel how something warm is touching me.

And "fühlen" can describe an emotional state.

> Ich fühle Trauer.
>
> I feel grief.

"empfinden" shares the latter meaning with "fühlen" and actually describes a state of mind.

> Ich empfinde Trauer.
>
> I feel grief.

In addition, "empfinden" can be used to express an opinion.

> Ich empfinde das als unfair.
>
> To me, that's unfair.

"empfinden" is always rather formal. More common alternatives to the latter sentence are

> Ich finde das unfair.
>
> I think that's unfair.

or

> Das ist unfair!

Comment: "sensing some directly" seems ambiguous to me and it doesn't help to differentiate between both verbs. From your example "Ich fühle wie etwas Warmes mich berührt", I think you mean "sensing something physically, with the sense of touch" (e.g. heat, cold)?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista yes, I meant "sensing something physically"

Answer (score 1):

To feel or "fühlen" is same in German as in English.

"empfinden" and "Empfindung" is related to "Feelings". You can feel and think about it as example you could say (psychologically):

- Ich empfinde als es beschämend was er macht.
- I think it's shameful what he is doing.

"Gefühl" and "fühlen" can mean:

You feel something on your skin or you feel sad (physically or psychologically).
This isn't possible with "empfinden/Empfindung"

Answer (score 0):

Empfinden" and "die Empfindung" relate to *psychological* feelings (happy, sad, etc).

So can "fühlen"and "das Gefühl". But these can also relate to *physical* feelings (hot, cold), which the words in the previous paragraph cannot.

When "fühlen" is used in the sense of "empfinden," one uses the reflexive form, [sich fühlen](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/30878/what-is-the-difference-between-f%C3%BChlen-and-sich-f%C3%BChlen/30894#30894).